# Condição inicial (IF) nao funciona

Tags: javascript, if, condição

Estou tentando fazer um jogo da velha. Até agora consegui fazer as marcações se alternem a cada turno e a função de apagar as marcações.

ps: estou usando cor preta e vermelha ao inves de bola e "x".

Meu problema é que as marcações alteram mesmo depois de marcadas se você clicar em cima dela denovo. Eu quero que uma vez clicadas os elementos mantenham suas marcações `(bgcolor)`.

http://jsfiddle.net/11nokxho/1

Para isso tentei solucionar colocando o primeiro if verificando se o background não possui cor inicial branca, se não possuir retornar falso e parar a função.

```
if(!casa.style.backgroundColor == "#FFF") return false;
```

Sendo que não funciona.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O operador lógico para diferente é: `!=`

E o retorno da propriedade `style.backgroundColor` é em rgb(x,x,x) e não em hexacolor, portanto tente com a seguinte sintaxe:

```
if(casa.style.backgroundColor != "rgb(255, 255, 255)" && casa.style.backgroundColor != "") return false;
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/11nokxho/2/)

Comment: Sobre o operador: !casa.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(255, 255, 255)". Claro que é, não? Tô confuso. Em fim

Comment: Não entendi porque funcionou para trocar de cor mesmo em HEX e nao funcionou para o primeiro teste?

Comment: não lembro se te marquei.

Comment: @ropbla9 Usar o `!` na frente da expressão indica que você deseja fazer a inversão do resultado, mas só funciona com boleanos, no caso, `casa.style.backgroundColor` retorna uma string, para funcionar como esperado, tem que enclausurar com parênteses assim: `!(casa.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(255, 255, 255)")` logo acho mais fácil usar `!=` diretamente...

Comment: e sobre o segundo comentário?